# What is wrong with my data format?

Tags: ios, sdk, warnings

I am using a tutorial app as a reference and I'm trying to make an app that converts shoe sizes from the U.S. shoe size to other the following countries: Europe, United Kingdom, and Japan.

I have a warning that pops up in my ViewController.m file stating:

> Data argument not used by format string

on the following code:

```
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"3f USS = 3f @", size, result, _countryNames[row]];
```

When I run the app, my DeBug Area pops with the following:

> 2013-07-15 10:50:07.377 ShoeSizeConverter[9617:c07] -[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7170c10
>      2013-07-15 10:50:07.379 ShoeSizeConverter[9617:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7170c10'
>
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0xc634 0xd25f 0x642dd 0x10e36b0 0x228efc0 0x228333c 0x228eeaf 0x1032bd 0x4bb56 0x4a66f 0x4a589 0x497e4 0x4961e 0x4a3d9 0x4d2d2 0xf799c 0x44574 0x4476f 0x44905 0x4d917 0x1196c 0x1294b 0x23cb5 0x24beb 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1217a 0x13ffc 0x1ecd 0x1df5)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: The warning is because you have 3 arguments but zero `%` signs in the format string.  The crash is because you did `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` on a UIView object.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a warning that pops up in my ViewController.m file stating
>   "Data argument not used by format string" on the following code:

You need to add percent signs before your format specifiers. Instead of `3f`, you need `%3f` and so on. So your format string should be:

```
@"%3f USS = %3f %@"
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning means that you are including data arguments (size, result, _countryNames[row]) but the format string has no reference to the data arguments. It looks like you are not including your percent signs, and need something like this:

```
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%3f USS = %3f %@", size, result, _countryNames[row]];
```

I believe the exception means that you have set your view as the data source of your UIPickerView, and your view does not respond to the numberOfComponentsInPickerView method. You probably mean to set the data source of your UIPickerView to the view controller (probably self) and make sure your view controller implements numberOfComponentsInPickerView.